# Trigonometric equation: $\ln(\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}= 2$

Tags: trigonometry

> $\ln(\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}= 2$

I am unable to solve it. I tried this way:

$(\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}= e^2$

I know that:

$\sin x + \cos x \le \sqrt2 $

$1+ \sin 2x \le 2 $

I don't know how to utilise this idea in my solution.

Comment: Note that $1+\sin(2x) = (\sin x + \cos x)^2$.

Comment: Btw, $\sin x + \cos x \le \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Do you mean $(\ln (\sin x + \cos x))^{1+\sin 2x)}$ or $\ln ((\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\ln(\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}= 2\iff\ln(\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}= \ln e^2\iff (\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}=e^2$$

but

$$(\sin x + \cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}=(\sin x + \cos x)^{(\sin x + \cos x)^2}\leq\sqrt2^{2}=2$$

Note

$$(\sin x + \cos x)^2=1+\sin 2x\le2\implies \sin x + \cos x \leq\sqrt 2$$

Comment: Do you mean there's no solution?

Comment: @Abcd, there is no real solution.

Comment: @Abcd yoe no real solution

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \sin x + \cos x$. Since $1+\sin 2x = (\sin x + \cos x)^2$, we have
$$ X^2 \ln X = 2. $$
Then
\begin{align}
X^2 \ln X^2 = 4 \implies Y \ln Y = 4
\end{align}
where $Y = X^2$.
It follows from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20ln%20y%20%3D%204) that $Y = e^{W(4)}$. 
Thus $X = e^{W(4)/2}$.
Since 
$$X = \sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4)$$
we conclude that
\begin{equation}
x = \sin^{-1}(e^{W(4)/2}/\sqrt{2}) - \pi/4.
\end{equation}

Added: However, since $e^{W(4)/2}/\sqrt{2} > 1$, there is no solution.

Comment: From your first line to second line of working... did you square the equation? If you did, then shouldn't it be $X^4 \ln X^2 = 4$?

Comment: what is $W$?....

Comment: @Landuros $2X^2 \ln X = 4$ and $X^22\ln X = X^2 \ln X^2 = 4$...

Comment: @Abcd It's the Lambert W function.

Comment: @Abcd Please find the link. [here] in the above.

Comment: @induction601 Oh, you multiplied by 2. My bad :)

Comment: +1 But the argument to $\arcsin$ in your final result is larger than $1$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks for pointing out. I added one more line :)

Comment: We have $e^{W(4)/2}\approx1.8$, and the amplitude of $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ is $\sqrt(2)\approx1.4$. So $e^{W(4)/2}=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ has no real solutions.

Comment: @DonAntonio. The exponent is $1+\sin(2x)$ my friend. Merry Xmas, amigo.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know, mon ami. That's what I wrote...et joyeux Noël !

Comment: @DonAntonio How are you interpreting $\log(\sqrt{2})^2$ to be $2$? It is either $\log(2)$ or $\log(\sqrt{2})\cdot \log(\sqrt{2})$ depending upon precedence of $\log$ versus exponent.

Comment: Yes, tthe problem in my comment is that the right hand equation is $\;2\;$ and not $\;\log2\;$ , as I thought at first...good one! The parentheses (or lack of) confused me...

Comment: I retract what I said about a solution existing. I had mis-typed something into a numerical calculator.

Comment: No solutions in the end, but I offer some critiques of the argument. (1) Early on you use $\ln(X^{X^2})=X^2\ln(X)$. This would not be valid if $X$ is negative and $X^2$ is an even integer, which in theory could be a solution. (2) From $Y=e^{W(4)}$, you conclude $X=e^{W(4)}$, but $X$ might be the negative square root. (3) In applying the $\arcsin$, you would miss one solution in the fundamental period $[0,2\pi)$, and of course all the solutions outside of that interval.